# Openvpn client can not reach a subnet which is reachable by the openvpn server

Tags: openvpn

I have setup a VPN server with private IP 10.0.35.10.
On this server, I can reach subnet 10.0.13.0/24; for example ssh, ping work for 10.0.13.10.
If I run a client on my laptop, I can connect to 10.0.35.10 but I can not on 10.0.13.10.

The server.conf is like

```
port xxxx
proto tcp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/xxxx.crt
key keys/xxxx.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh keys/dh2048.pem
server 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.0.13.0 255.255.255.255" 
push "route 10.0.35.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

On the server, the routes are :

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.35.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.13.0       10.0.35.1       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.35.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.254.0   192.168.254.2   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.254.2   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

On the VPN client (my laptop) :

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.13.0       192.168.254.102 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.0.35.0       192.168.254.102 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.254.0   192.168.254.102 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.254.102 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Thanks for any hint

Karim

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I believe this is an issue with your subnet mask. You are using a `/32` which maps to a single IP address. You probably want `/24` which will allow you to access `10.0.13.1` to `10.0.13.254` rather than just `10.0.13.1`.

So:

```
push "route 10.0.13.0 255.255.255.255"
```

should be changed to:

```
push "route 10.0.13.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: Thanks ! Did it but it is not better :-(

Comment: @KarimB I don't know what it could be then, but maybe try checking to see if your firewall is blocking it? You might be able to find more help on serverfault or the OpenVPN forums.